# How can I run Process in .NET?

Tags: c#

How can I run Process in C# ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find your answers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) method:

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe");
```

And if you want to pass arguments:

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe", "test.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the [Process Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccf1tfx0(v=VS.71).aspx)  which can be used to start and control processes.